# Vertial column heading text in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to write a angular ui-grid (the new ng-grid) with vertical text in the column headings but having some interesting results using the standard CSS trick

```
.blue { 
  color: blue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left;
    height:100px;
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CtDEcgSrebLFnBXcMrjS?p=preview

I just wondered if this were possible and if anyone had any knowledge of it?

Comment: What result do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably provide your own header cell template and modify the way the header is created.

Here is a simple example

```
function headerCellTemplate() {
    return $timeout(function() {
      $scope.waiting = 'Done!';
      $interval.cancel(sec);
      $scope.wait = '';
      return "<div ng-class=\"{ 'sortable': sortable }\"><!-- <div class=\"ui-grid-vertical-bar\">&nbsp;</div> --><div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents verticalText\" col-index=\"renderIndex\"><p class=\"verticalTextSpan\">{{ col.displayName CUSTOM_FILTERS }}</p> <span ui-grid-visible=\"col.sort.direction\" ng-class=\"{ 'ui-grid-icon-up-dir': col.sort.direction == asc, 'ui-grid-icon-down-dir': col.sort.direction == desc, 'ui-grid-icon-blank': !col.sort.direction }\">&nbsp;</span></div><div class=\"ui-grid-column-menu-button\" ng-if=\"grid.options.enableColumnMenus && !col.isRowHeader  && col.colDef.enableColumnMenu !== false\" ng-click=\"toggleMenu($event)\" ng-class=\"{'ui-grid-column-menu-button-last-col': isLastCol}\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-angle-down\">&nbsp;</i></div><div ng-if=\"filterable\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-container\" ng-repeat=\"colFilter in col.filters\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"ui-grid-filter-input\" ng-model=\"colFilter.term\" ng-attr-placeholder=\"{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}\"><div class=\"ui-grid-filter-button\" ng-click=\"colFilter.term = null\"><i class=\"ui-grid-icon-cancel\" ng-show=\"!!colFilter.term\">&nbsp;</i><!-- use !! because angular interprets 'f' as false --></div></div></div>";
    }, 10);
  }
```

Add this header cell template to the columns where you need vertical text. The css can be modified to your needs,

```
.verticalText
{
  height:100px;
}

.verticalTextSpan
{
  margin:auto;
  padding-left:50px;
     -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/d78TfLAgbuAT0ungoNLR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, it's still a bit tricky to get it to work with a constantly changing number of columns but this did the trick for a constant table size.